# More instances of SimpleSlider on ajax calls are created

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a trouble with SimpleSlider on Ajax Callback. I load my data from ajax on scrolling and initialize the simpleslider, but I get the simpleslider twice in previous elements as seen in the image below.

[image: twice slider]

Here is the code I use

```
currentRequest = $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    context: document.body,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: params,
    success: function (result, status) {
        if (result.data) {
            var $input = $(".schiebe-filter .range-input");
            var slider = $input.data("slider-object");
            // twice slider !
            //if (!slider) {
            $input.simpleSlider({
                range: [1, 100],
                value: 80,
                step: 1,
                snap: false
            }).bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
                $(this).parent().find('.pull-right').text(data.value + '%' + ' \u00e4hnliche');
                $(this).parent().find('.pull-left').text('keywords ' + (100 - data.value) + '%');
            });
            //}
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        $('#loader').addClass('nomore');
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
});
```

How can I solve this?